# Characteristic function of the exponential

Tags: probability, complex-analysis, analysis

In my book (Jacod, Protter p.108) it is:
$$
\frac{a^2}{a^2+b^2}-i\frac{ab}{a^2+b^2}=\frac{a}{a-ib}
$$
at the end, in the last equation, but for me:
$$
\frac{a^2}{a^2+b^2}-i\frac{ab}{a^2+b^2}=\frac{a^2-iab}{(a+ib)(a-ib)}=\frac{a(a-ib)}{(a+ib)(a-ib)}=\frac{a}{a+ib}
$$
I put a Picture in from the book. It is the very last equation at the end. How is the proof still possible if we just block out the typo that there seems to be as the commentators allready expressed down below.

[image: The proof from the book]

Comment: Thanks for adding an excerpt from the book. I've added an answer that will save you having to create a new question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typo is in the sign of the imaginary part on the left-hand side, not on the right; the characteristic function is certainly $\frac{\lambda}{\lambda-iu}$. Note that$$\Im\varphi_X(u)=\left.\frac{\lambda}{\lambda^2+u^2}e^{-\lambda x}(-u\cos ux-\lambda\sin ux)\right|_0^\infty=+\frac{\lambda u}{\lambda^2+u^2}.$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $a=b=1$, $$LHS=\frac12-\frac{i}{2}=\frac{1-i}{2}=\frac{2}{2(1+i)}=\frac{1}{1+i}.$$

Hence, the book is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a typo, the right Hand side must be $$\frac{a}{a+bi}$$

Comment: Thank you, but then the whole proof about the characterisctic function makes no sense, because it is wrong then.